# using Remix in solidity encounter error: Error: invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.1.1)

Tags: solidity

using Remix, write something about a contract in solidity.
after compiling, nothing wrong.
But after deployment,there is an error :

```
Error: invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="", 

                    code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.1.1)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show steps to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

That error happens when you submit a wrong argument to the contract. if I submit empty input but contract needs at least 100 wei:

[image]